# How to close all Puma server connections in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

I have Rails app with Puma as a server from which I fork a process as a daemon

example:

```
fork do
  Process.daemon # to detach from terminal
  sleep
end
```

The problem is that forked process inherits all Puma connections to ports or unix sockets.
Anybody knows how to close all those Puma connections?

Comment: if you kill the fork does it close the connection?  I'm not able to try right this second.  ie `pid = fork { Process.daemon }` then `Process.kill("HUP", pid)`

Comment: it doesn't help. I think that `pid = fork { Process.daemon; sleep }` just terminates itself - the part in `pid`

Comment: Is using `spawn` an option vs `fork`?